# Adjusting text border thickness in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, text

MapInfo allows you to add an outline to your text by using the 'border' or 'halo' function. Is there any way to customise the thickness of these outlines? I find the standard setting far too thick, and adds to much clutter to my maps.

Comment: Certainly in versions 12 and under you cannot. I don't include 12.5 in this as I haven't got it installed so am unable to check whether this has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. There's no extra options to customize the appearance of these borders.